# Is there a cache mechanism with getrawtransaction?

Tags: json-rpc, cache, getrawtransaction

I am currently working on a script that parses every BTC transaction from the beginning of the blockchain. My goal is to record summaries about each transaction in database, after synthesizing it.

While working on this, I observed that the first time I am using `getrawtransaction`, for 1000 transactions (i.e., 1000 RPCs), it takes between 20 and 30 seconds.

The second time I do the RPCs, for the same 1000 transactions, it takes less than 1 second.

My conclusion is that there is some caching mechanism set up, somewhere. I do not know if it is caching at the OS layer or at the software layer, though, and cannot manage to find any documentation on this.
Incidentally, I would like to be able to manage this mechanism to allow me to make requests more quickly.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're observing the disk cache. When you call `getrawtransaction`, Bitcoin Core first needs to check the transaction index (enabled by `-txindex`) and then load the transaction from its `blk*.dat` file (and `rev*.dat` file if you're also requesting prevouts), all of which are operations that access the disk. As far as I know, Bitcoin Core itself doesn't have a cache that would help in this situation.

Side note, if you want to process the entire blockchain with an external program, I'd recommend using `getblock` instead of `getrawtransaction`.

Comment: The database system Bitcoin Core uses for the txindex is LevelDB, which does have a small in-memory cache in user space. Still, I'd expect that the majority of what OP is observing is indeed the operating system's disk cache.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The disk cache theory makes sense, and I noted your advice about `getblock`.

Comment: @vojtěch-strnad just to let you know that using `getblock` and parsing the transactions from there, instead of using `getrawtransaction`, has divided the time of my program by 3. Many thanks again!